# Mac System Preference Screen Saver "Start after:" setting is always disabled

Tags: screensaver

I've been searching for the answer for a while, but I haven't been able figure it out.

I'd like to lower start time of my Mac's screen saver, but it's always disabled, and I cannot make it go up/down.

[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this your own personal Mac or a work mac.

Comment: Mine's like this too, set to 5 min, it's a corp laptop and a policy/profile is enforcing it, see the dup I linked.